# How to serve static content using Spock (Haskell)?

Tags: haskell, server, haskell-stack, static-content, haskell-spock

I am running a Spock server and wanting to serve some static content.
I am using `respondMiddleware` function from the "Web.Spock.Action" package.

The signature is:

```
    respondMiddleware :: Monad m => Middleware -> ActionCtxT ctx m a
```

I am getting this "Middleware" using the `staticPolicy` function from "Network.Wai.Middleware.Static" package

```
    staticPolicy :: Policy -> Middleware
```

And the "Policy" using `addBase` from "Network.Wai.Middleware.Static" package

```
    addBase :: String -> Policy
```

Here is my codeblock:

```
    get ("/") $
      respondMiddleware $ staticPolicy $ addBase ("static")
```

The `static` has an `index.html` and the related JS and CSS files and it is placed in the root directory of the stack project. The error I get is `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Spock, so this may be wrong: The path `"/"` in your RouteSpec doesn't have a wildcard, so I think that will only match *exactly* `/`. I suspect what you want is `middleware $ staticPolicy $ addBase "static"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do this is using the `html` function from the [Web.Spock.Action](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Spock-core-0.12.0.0/docs/Web-Spock-Action.html) package.

I used a jinja templating using ginger to parameterize my html file and then served it using the `html` function.

```
import qualified Web.Spock.Action as SA

serveHtml :: JinjaTemplate -> SA.ActionT (LoggingT IO) ()
serveHtml tmplt = SA.html tmplt
```